# Rails ArgumentError in OrdersController#new validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, validation, nomethoderror

Second question on here, I'd really like to solve this one myself but  I just don't know where to start to debug it.

So here is my error in the browser (which occurs when I go to check out and enter my details in order/_form.html.erb)

> ArgumentError in OrdersController#new
>
> You need to supply at least one validation
>
> Rails.root: C:/Users/Ruby/rails_practice/depot4
>   Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>
> app/models/payment_type.rb:6:in `<class:PaymentType>'
>   app/models/payment_type.rb:1:in`'
>   app/models/order.rb:7:in `<class:Order>'
>   app/models/order.rb:1:in`'
>   app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:1:in `'

And here is my def new in OrdersController:

```
def new
  @cart = current_cart
  if @cart.line_items.empty?
    redirect_to store_url, :notice => "Your cart is empty"
    return
  end

  @hide_checkout_button = true
  @order = Order.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @order }
  end
end
```

The thing is that I haven't touch def new, I've been working on def create, which is here:

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(params[:order])
  @order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)
  @cart = current_cart
  @hide_checkout_button = true
  pay_type = PaymentType.find( :conditions => ['pay_type = ?', @order.pay_type] )
  @order.payment_type_id = pay_type.id

  respond_to do |format|
    if @order.save
      Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
      session[:cart_id] = nil
      format.html { redirect_to(store_url, :notice => 'Thank you for your order.') }
      format.json { render json: @order, status: :created, location: @order }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

What I am trying to do there is create an order which is which `belongs_to` a `payment_type` and `has_many line_items` which `belongs_to` a cart.

Incidentally, I am also trying to `hide_checkout_button` with an instance variable when I am on the order page.

The Orders table has a foreign key to the `PaymentTypes` table and I am trying to find the correct id from this `PaymentTypes` table for the `payment_type` submitted by the user.

If I comment out these two lines:

```
pay_type = PaymentType.find( :conditions => ['pay_type = ?', @order.pay_type] )
@order.payment_type_id = pay_type.id
```

Sometimes I get a different error:

> NoMethodError in OrdersController#new
>
> undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass

I think this is to do with incorrect caching in the browser but I'm not sure what the connection is.

I will update with the rest after I post this first

---

*Part deux*

I know that this is about validation, but I can't see what I am doing wrong... order.rb:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :email, :name, :pay_type, :payment_type_id, :cart_id, 
  :product_id

  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :payment_type

  PAYMENT_TYPES = PaymentType.pluck(:pay_type)

  validates :name, :address, :email, :pay_type, :presence => true
  validates :pay_type, :inclusion => PAYMENT_TYPES
```

And then you've got the other side of that `belongs_to` in `payment_type.rb`

```
class PaymentType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :pay_type

  has_many :orders

  validates ***:pay_type,*** :uniqueness
end
```

I know that I am totally just confusing things but I have one fail in the functionals tests and one error that has something to do with updating an order but I don't know what yet. I am going to work on them to see if by solving them I inadvertently solve this weird error.

If anyone can give me tips on hacking and debugging in rails that would be great. I would love to be able to solve this without typing all of this in here.

I don't think the server trace gives any more information than the browser window in this case but if you need it, or anything else please ask.

UPDATE:

So my problem is that I know how to solve it with a global variable in payment_type.rb, but this means that I have one column of payment types in the Orders table and another of names and payment_type_ids in another column, which is the foreign key.

Since I have the foreign key I shouldn't need a specific column for payment_types in the Orders table. I should just be able to see the value from the PaymentType table in the Orders view.

How do you do this without a Global variable?

UPDATE deux:

Ok, so I never posted this before (from orders_form.html.erb):

```
26:   <div class="field">
27:     <%= f.label :pay_type %><br />
28:     <%= f.select :pay_type, PaymentType::PAYMENT_TYPES,
29:                      :prompt => 'Select a payment method' %>
30:   </div>
31:   <div class="actions">
```

So I've tried to select for :pay_type in Orders but given options from :pay_type in PaymentTypes.

I can't imagine that matters does it? Seems to be where my problem lies, but can't be sure.

Comment: `app/models/payment_type.rb:6:in <class:PaymentType>' ` means the error was first raised here, so can you add your PaymentType model to your post pleasE?

Comment: Also Im not sure you can have a `new` action in a controller, it might be a reserved word.

Comment: please show your `payment_type.rb` and `order.rb`

Comment: Cheers for the quick response guys, any ideas?

Comment: ok, the errors because you don't set validates for attributes in PaymenType, what attribute you want it's unique?

Comment: Oh I am such a shithead, I just saw "validates :uniqueness". I guess I have been studying all day and have become a bit clueless. Don't I look like a tool...

Comment: i think you want: `validates :pay_type_id, :uniqueness => true`

Comment: Cheers Kien, but amazingly it still doesn't work, I get the same error as earlier.

Comment: change your `validates :pay_type...` like @Paulo's answer, it's also wrong.

Comment: I know there must be something wrong with the array PAYMENT_TYPES, but I can't figure it out...

Comment: try run in console `PAYMENT_TYPES = PaymentType.pluck(:pay_type)` to see what it returns

Comment: why do you have `:pay_type` in `Order.rb`?

Comment: Same error as in the browser.

That is the line causing the trouble, but look at the docs it just creates an array out of the entries in a column. And before I had an array constant, which worked fine...

Comment: remove `:pay_type` in your `Order.rb`, and change `@order.pay_type` to `@order.payment_type_id.pay_type`

Comment: Thats it, I shouldn't have had PAYMENT_TYPES in order.rb. I have it there because that was where it was as an array constant, which didn't cause any issue.

I've made it a global variable and put it in payment_type.rb

Comment: So are you solved your problem?

Comment: I'll update the post :-)

Comment: Updated at bottom, cheers Kien :-)

Comment: i don't understand what you want to do now :(

Comment: if you want to display all payment type in new order view, try use this code in your form: `<%= f.select :payment_type_id, PaymentType.all, :id, :pay_type %>`

Comment: I am struggling here.

I've Updated the code (in bold) to show you what I've done, but I am getting a similar exception to the last one except this time it is only in order.rb line 7.

Kien, can you explain your answer please? I can really get my head around that. Do you mean " change @order.pay_type to @order.payment_type_id.pay_type" in OrdersController#create?

Comment: Thanks for that last message Kien :-)

Comment: yes, in this: `['pay_type = ?', @order.pay_type]`, your @order don't have attribute or method called pay_type, so it has error `NoMethodError`

Comment: one more, this is also can used for create select in views: `<%= f.collection_select :payment_type_id, PaymentType.all, :id , :pay_type %>`

Comment: Oh but that is what I mean by there being two columns, one in each table, doing the same thing.

Orders and PaymentTypes both have columns called pay_type. I want to get rid of the pay_type in Orders because it is messy, so I'll try your code to do this thanks. But @order does have a method call .pay_type

I'm slow not because need break for dinner. Thanks for trying :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the syntax of your validate inclusion of is wrong. It should be something like:

validates :pay_type, :inclusion => { :in => PAYMENT_TYPES }

Comment: Cheers Paulo, doesn't seem to do anything though